# Map domain name in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, localhost

Is there a way to map a domain name to a local project instead of use localhost?

i need to resolve a live url locally for development purpose

Comment: Solved:
just write this
127.0.0.1       file.domain.com
::1 file.domain.com
in this file
%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts